# Java - exception handling and force full exit from the system

Tags: java, exception

Please excuse me for this kind of questions here but I am sure to get good explanation with sample which will make to have better understanding about java.

when the `System.exit(0);` gets executed, the system will break the execution flow and come out the system. this is what is my understanding as of now but I have came across some thing like the below :

```
Example 1 : 

class FinallySystemExit
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
try
{
int a=2/0;
System.exit(0);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println("i am in catch block");
}
finally
{
System.out.println("finally");
}
}
}
```

my understanding about the above code is it will not print anything and `exit` from the system but the output is :

```
i am in catch block
finally

Example 2

class FinallySystemExit
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
try
{
int a=2/1;
System.exit(0);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println("i am in catch block");
}
finally
{
System.out.println("finally");
}
}
}
```

when i execute the above code `it prints nothing`

The difference between two programs are :

```
First Program : 

int a=2/0;
```

and the

```
 Second Program : 

int a=2/1;
```

I am totally confused and my basic understanding is broken here.

Could some one explain the reason please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Example 1` :
You perform `int a=2/0;`

This will throw `java.lang.ArithmeticException` as you are `dividing a number by zero`.
As your code is surrounded by `try - catch` the exception is caught and it printed the statement in `catch block` and went to `finally` block

In `Example 2:`
You perform `int a=2/1;`
So there is no problem at all.

After executing the above line, your program executed `System.exit(0);`. So No chance of executing the finally block. That is the reason you don't get any output in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In the first snippet, there is Divide-by-zero error and so the System.exit() is not even called. In the second snippet System.exit() is called and so the JVM exited